# How to update when using angularFireCollection instead of angularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have read the docs and I see there is an update method.  However I am not having any luck with it.  I get "Cannot call method 'update' of undefined".  I can however change update to 'add' and the function works.  I am doing something wrong, I just don't know what..

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','angularFireCollection',     function($scope, angularFireCollection) {
    var url = 'https://myapp.firebaseio.com/genre';
    $scope.genres = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'genres');

    $scope.vote = function(){
      this.artist.votes=this.artist.votes + 1;


      $scope.genres.update(this); // this update is not working.


    }
  }]);
}).call(this);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `this` in the context of the function? You should call $scope.genres.update with either an item from the collection, or an ID. For example, this works:

```js
$scope.genres = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'genres');
$scope.vote = function() {
  var item = $scope.genres[0];
  item.votes++;
  $scope.genres.update(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank You. "this" didn't seem right to me, but I thought that was the same as your item above in essence.  I had to keep the this.artist.votes++ to update my $scope.